# SE chat site does not remember last selected tab when using HTTPS

Tags: bug, chat, ssl

I have noticed that when using the HTTP version of the [SE chat site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) that if I say go to the `favorites` section and go into a chat room, or I simply go to that section or another section and leave the site, when I come back it will be on the tab I last left it on which is rather nice and useful because I want it to always be on the `favorites` tab.

However on the HTTPS version of the site this functionality does not work for every time I go to the site it ignores my last selected tab and just takes me to the `site` tab by default which I find rather annoying.

My browser is Firefox 47.

Comment: I was almost going to comment that reproduced, but then it suddenly started working... Weird.

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: I am, it's been not working for about half a year now (ever since I started using the HTTPS version).

Comment: @nicael: What I find most annoying though is the fact that I enter a room by click on it in my favorites list, but then when I `leave` the room I am taken to the `site` tab instead of the `favorites` tab from which I came (or wherever I came from). And I am sure that it remembered on the HTTP version.